# How did Yakone learn bloodbending?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

1. Hama is self-taught.
2. Katara learned from Hama.
3. Tarrlok learned from Yakone.
4. [ATLA/TLOK spoiler]

> Amon/Noatak learned from Yakone too.

5. Yakone learned from who/whom?

Comment: Self-taught, it would appear; https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Yakone#cite_note-OP-1

Comment: @Valorum Huh? I checked those 5 places where that was cited. I didn't see anything there....except 'He had even discovered a way to use bloodbending without the presence of the full moon.' ? Oh is that it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to [Avatar.fandom - Bloodbending](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Bloodbending):
>
> > Following the end of the Hundred Year War, knowledge regarding bloodbending became widespread and, with Katara's involvement, the United Republic of Nations outlawed the bending art sometime before 128 AG. Regardless, a man named Yakone had the unique ability to use bloodbending without the need of a full moon and used this skill to rule Republic City from its "rotten underbelly", becoming the city's most notorious criminal malefactor in a matter of years.

So through this it seems Yakone self-taught himself this, **or** he gained this ability somehow without learning initially and mastered it afterwards, which is why it was *unique*.

Answer (score -1):

## Answer 2 of 2, an a posteriori answer:

Kinda lame compared to [Answer 1 of 2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/267242).

See [2:00 in this scene](https://youtu.be/XRIhg-pxhk8?t=120) when Yakone explains bloodbending to Tarrlok aaaaand

[TLOK s1 spoiler]

> to Amon/Noatak, Tarrlok's older sibling and Yakone's 1st child.

Yakone says

> Our family has the strongest line of bloodbenders in history.
>
> [image]

I don't think really there's a need to have this as an explanation as to why Yakone could bloodbend though.

Note: Re the [a priori answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/267242) I gave:

However for some reason Tarrlok asks 'What's bloodbending?' Ah well maybe their village was just so isolated or maybe bloodbending isn't something you tell little kids about.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question of where he learned his skill

Comment: @Valorum from parents?!??!

Comment: I'm not seeing it. He could just as easily be referring to himself and his kids as the "strongest line" without any need to include his parents

Comment: @Valorum lol how could you have strongest line before even you know Gasai how they'll turn out?